# Switch to Ubuntu devel

Tags: apt

I want to switch to Ubuntu devel sources. What is the best way to switch to it??

By "best", I meant what else should I do before or after editing the `apt sources` file.

Comment: I don't consider *development* releases of Ubuntu on-topic for this site, however normal procedures can be used to upgrade to the next release (ie. if you're currently on 23.04 you can move to it using normal procedures with `-d`).  I take it you want *devel* and not where `-d` will put you (ie. to *mantic* which is much the same anyway)..  To go to *devel* I'd recommend going thru *mantic* first  (*though depending on when it's done, you won't notice any package upgrades when you switch to devel anyway*)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu)

Comment: @guiverc It is not only about upgrading ubuntu. I want to get the devel packages for ubuntu. Sort of a rolling packages thing..

Comment: If you read https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic you'll note only *standard* supported release of Ubuntu are on-topic, ie. the newest release on-topic on this site is *lunar* or the current *stable* release. You're wanting to move to #ubuntu+1 which is supported on IRC, at Ubuntu Forums & other sites but not here thus my wording. Problems can occur on *development* products so you should be able to deal with issues when they occur, and thus know enough to explore & work it out from existing tools (ie. `-d` option is documented if you look).

Comment: You also ask for the *best* way, ie. seeking *opinions* which are off-topic on this site as well; as they're better suited to Forums and not Q&A sites like this. https://ubuntuforums.org is the address of Ubuntu Forums, which allows #ubuntu+1 questions which are deemed off-topic here. I've already commented on some of my approach; as I only go to current *development* release myself I also check & *houseclean* my system every six moths before moving back to #ubuntu+1 (release of *lunar* as 23.04 was thursday; I was on *mantic* before monday if I recall correctly) so won't have *houseclean*

Comment: You could check out [Rhino Linux](https://rhinolinux.org/) - which is based on Ubuntu Rolling Rhino - and off-topic here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An overview of switching to the development (pre-release) of Ubuntu. It's not detailed simply because most folks with sufficient skill and experience to use development version of Ubuntu already can locate (or already know) more detail.

1. Skills: Testers and developers are expected to know how to troubleshoot, use the bug reporting system effectively, locate and use the published documentation, use apt and virtual machines to accomplish their goals, and other skills.
2. Communicate: Join the pre-release discussion and announcement mailing lists and testing online groups.

   - AskUbuntu is not one of those groups; it specializes in *released* software technical support only.
3. To actually begin testing or developing software, the usual method is to spin up a virtual machine and install the pre-release daily .iso image.

   For switching on bare metal (warning: It's a one-way trip. You cannot 'switch back'), plain old `do-release-update -d` *without* editing apt sources is the usual way. This method is disabled during the weeks after a new release until the next +1 repos are set up. There are other methods, too.